# Nested Mongoose queries data not showing on GraphQL query

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql, apollo-server

I'm trying to create an API using Apollo-server with GraphQL and Mongoose.
My problem is that the query to Mongoose does return the data, but the GraphQL model shows as `null` when I test.

I've tried different methods and using promises.

```
    type Articulo {
        id: ID
        nombre: String
        codigoDeBarras: String
        codigo: String
    }
    type EntradaInventario {
        id: ID
        articulo: Articulo
        inventario: Inventario
        cantidad: Float
    }
    type Almacen {
        id: ID
        nombre: String
    }
    type Inventario {
        id: ID
        almacen: Almacen
        nombre: String
    }
    type Query {
        articulo(codigoDeBarras: String): Articulo
        entradaInventario(inventario: String): [EntradaInventario]
    }
    type Mutation {
        addEntradaInventario(idArticulo: String, idInventario: String, cantidad: Float): EntradaInventario
        addAlmacen(nombre: String): Almacen
        addInventario(idAlmacen: String, nombre: String): Inventario
    }
    const EntradaInventarioModel = Mongoose.model("EntradaInventario", {
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    idArticulo: {type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Articulo'},
    idInventario: {type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Inventario'},
    cantidad: Number
}, "entradainventarios");

    Query: {
        articulo: (_, args) => ArticuloModel.findOne({
            'codigoDeBarras': args.codigoDeBarras
        }).exec(),
        entradaInventario: (_, args) => 
            EntradaInventarioModel.find({idInventario: args.inventario})
            .populate('idArticulo')
            .exec(),
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use the populate on the Parent model. You should instead define how to query the nested model in the EntradaInventario resolvers.

Inventory should look something like this:

```
Inventory : {
    articulo: async (parent, args, { }) => {
      return await Articulo.findOne({
        _id: parent.idArticulo,
      });
    },
  }
```

Here is a repo that does just that and is a good example https://github.com/the-road-to-graphql/fullstack-apollo-express-mongodb-boilerplate

Comment: should inventory be a new query or be inside the entradaInventario resolver?

Comment: your `entradaInventario` query should just have the `EntradaInventarioModel.find({idInventario: args.inventario})` command. The `EntradaInventario` type  should have a resolver of how to query articulo and inventario fields on that type

Comment: GraphQL will know to go the resolvers of `EntradaInventario` to fetch the articulo and inventario